# ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from partially initialized module 'app'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I keep gettting this error whenever i try running my main.py
it is really frustrating me because I can't seem to figure the exact problem is. Any help I'd appreciate.

## My error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\fusco\PycharmProjects\booklibrary\main.py", line 1, in 
> from app import db
> File "C:\Users\fusco\PycharmProjects\booklibrary\app.py", line 4, in 
> from model import User as User
> File "C:\Users\fusco\PycharmProjects\booklibrary\model.py", line 3, in 
> from app import db
> ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from partially initialized module 'app' (most likely due to a circular import)

(C:\Users\fusco\PycharmProjects\booklibrary\app.py)

## my model.py

```
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from app import db
from flask_login import UserMixin

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
first_name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
last_name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
contact = relationship("Contact", uselist=False, backref="user")
password = relationship("Password", uselist=False, backref="user")
books = relationship('Book', secondary='userbook', backref="user")
roles = relationship('Role', secondary='userrole', backref="user")

class Book(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
title = db.Column(db.String(300), unique=True)
isbn = db.Column(db.String(11), unique=True)
year = db.Column(db.String(4))
users = relationship('User', secondary='userbook', backref="book")

class Contact(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
phone_number1 = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
phone_number2 = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
address = db.Column(db.String(200))
user_id = db.Column(db.integer, ForeignKey=('user.id'))

class Password(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
password = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True, )
user_id = db.Column(db.integer, ForeignKey=('user.id'))

class Role(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, )
users = relationship('User', secondary='user_role', backref="role")

class UserRole(db.Model):
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('role.id'), primary_key=True)

class UserBook(db.Model):
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('book.id'), primary_key=True)
```

## #My app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from model import User

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecret'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///bookdb'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
```

## My main.py

```
from app import db
from routes import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.app_context().push()
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I would appreciate any help on this right now. Thank you

Comment: main tries to import app which tries to import model which tries to import app again. Its a couple of steps deep, but app is trying to import itself. That's a circular import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that in `model.py` you're trying to import `db` from `app.py` and in `app.py` you're trying to import `User` from `model.py`. This is called circular import as stated in the error message.

The root cause of this problem is `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`, which I do not believe is a good practice because of this circular import issue. According to the [documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/quickstart/) of `flask_sqlalchemy`, you should use a `DeclarativeBase` to create your `db` object. So something like:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
  pass

db = SQLAlchemy(model_class=Base)
```

(Credit: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/quickstart/)

Since `db` is no longer dependent on `app`, you can move this piece of code into its own file, something like `database.py`, and import `db` from `database.py` in your `model.py`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is more than helpful bruh! thanks. Although I had to make some few changes to my code but this was my root solution. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helps.